# Can't download Font Awesome 4.7 anymore?

Tags: font-awesome

The link seem to be broken:
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Any alternative link?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can find it on GitHub :
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/tag/v4.7.0

I download it successfully but I didn't try it, I think it will work

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. More specifically the zip file can be downloaded from https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v4.7.0.zip

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is working. maybe you hit it during an outage. But both your direct link or from the download button on the screen [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) work.

Comment: The link works, I can confirm, but it redirects. If you want to download from cmdline, you need to make sure that the tool follows redirections. Works out of the box with `wget`. For cURL, use `curl -L`.

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome creators are going to upgrade from v5 to v6 so the v4 may be completely dropped soon.
You can still [preview and search](https://fontawesome-v4.github.io/icons) icons or download [FontAwesome v4.7 icons on Github](https://fontawesome-v4.github.io).